# Cloud API Call "GET" to PNG

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-functions, flutterflow

I'm having trouble processing PNG data from a Cloud Api "GET" call.

It looks like this: I execute "GET" and process the received response as "Raw body Text" in my function, then save it in Firebase. The function is executed, the file has the correct size, but the file does not open after downloading. The image comes from DALL-E and I work in Flutterlow. When I perform a GET via Postman, I get a PNG image.

This is my code, what am I doing wrong?

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

Future<void> saveDataToFirebaseStorage(String bytes) async {
  // Converting input to Uint8List
  Uint8List data = Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode(bytes));

  // Retrieving the currently logged in user
  var currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  if (currentUser != null) {
    // Specifying the file path in Firebase Storage
    String filePath = 'users/${currentUser.uid}/data_file';

    // Reference to Firebase Storage
    Reference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(filePath);

    // Data transfer
    try {
      await ref.putData(data);
      print("The data was saved to Firebase Storage");
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error saving data: $e");
    }
  } else {
    print("No user logged in");
  }
}
```